# Android application to download pre defined files over WiFi automatically

Tags: android, download-manager, wifi

I need to download various files for my desktop over college WiFi using my android phone, but I need this to be done automatically.

So, for example, I would have a text file with links on each line. I would import this text file to the app. When I later connect to WiFi, this app will start to download these files one by one.

**Compulsory features:**

- Should be able to receive links somehow beforehand.
- Should download files only over WiFi, not 3g/gprs.
- Should work on android 4.0+

**Important features:**

- Should be able to accept links in a bunch, preferably in text format.

**Other features:**

- Preference to free app.
- Should not have limit on number of links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever it comes to automation, first thing coming to mind is **[Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm):** over at [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) we sometimes think this app is the answer to every second question. I'm a *Tasker* user myself, so I can say from my own experience it's a very powerful tool.

I'm not using it for anything like what you've defined, but from the features available I know it's capable of this. You'll have to invest some time to build a corresponding profile, but I'll give you a raw idea/concept here. *Tasker* executes "tasks" on "conditions", so you can think of it as "whenever [condition] is met, [task] will be executed". So let's go for a "pseudo-code" example:

- **Conditions:**

  - WiFi connected (parameter: your WiFi's SSID)
  - File exists (your input file)
- **Task:**

  - Change to target directory
  - Read the file line by line. For each $line: HTTP_GET $line
  - Delete/rename (your input file – to avoid it being processed in an endless loop)

#### How it meets your requirements:

- **Should be able to receive links somehow beforehand:** Yes
- **Should download files only over WiFi, not 3g/gprs:** Yes (configurable, so you also could do it the other way around ;)
- **Should work on android 4.0+:** Yes (I use it a.o. on 4.0)
- **Should be able to accept links in a bunch, preferably in text format:** Yes, can process a file line-by-line as outlined
- **Should not have limit on number of links:** I'm not aware of any. Though size of the input file might matter :)
- **Preference to free app:** Unfortunately not. But there's a free 7-day trial available on their homepage. Trial period can be extended in 7-day-intervals with a trick, though: Export the configuration, uninstall the app, re-install the app, import configuration (this hint comes from the developer himself, so I freely mention it here).

To give you some visual, here are some screenshots:

[image: Tasker] [image: Tasker] [image: Tasker]
<sup>Some screenshots to demonstrate the powers of *Tasker* (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

*Tasker* can be very complex, though – that comes with its powers. To lookup its possibilities, there's a [User Guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/) available. The [Tasker Wiki](http://tasker.wikidot.com/) also has useful resources, like a walk-through to get a first feeling, or example profiles created by other users.

Comment: It works perfectly. Just one thing, in the HTTP_GET task, what do I put in server:port? what server and what port does it want?

Comment: If it "works perfectly" already, I wouldn't care :) But usually, that's the "remote server". For a "standard one", you put e.g. "www.example.com" and "80". As you would do in your browser, where you normally omit the "default port" (80). So for "www.johndoe.com:8080" it would be "www.johndoe.com" and "8080" ;)

Comment: Answer to that detail also [here on our sister site](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/77871/16575) – my previous comment obviously was a bit confusing (quoted out of my head, I didn't remember the Tasker UI details correctly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Several good answers to [this Android Stack Exchange question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77423/folder-that-automatically-uploads-to-phone?newsletter=1&nlcode=241017%7C8ff3) I especially like [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) which seems like it could answer most if not all of your requirements.  There is a lot more detail in the answer referenced.

To quote the web site:

> FolderSync is a application that enables simple sync to cloud based
>   storage to and from local folders on the device memory card. It
>   currently support multiple OneDrive, Copy.com, Dropbox, Dump Truck,
>   SugarSync, Bitcasa, Ubuntu One, Box.net, LiveDrive, HiDrive, Google
>   Docs, NetDocuments, Amazon S3, FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WebDAV or windows
>   share (Samba/CIFS) accounts, and support for more platforms are
>   planned. Read-only access to protected file-system also supported -
>   requires root.

And the answer:

> Then either chose for some "auto-check" (e.g. have it synced every
>   night), or push the button manually. Using the paid version, you could
>   even bring in tasker – which is what I do: "Every night at 3am, when
>   connected to any power source and to MY_WIFI network → Sync all my
>   backups, photos, whatsnots" :)

Comment: Could you explain how that answer is helpful to me? Can I use foldersync somehow to download files over internet?

Comment: Yes it could. Trouble is: it can not read your list, it only matches existing directories – so Steve probably missed (or mis-interpreted) your "important features" part. // @Steve: files to be downloaded should be specified by a text file, and might reside in different locations. I don't think *FolderSync* covers that.